# Compiling in cygwin with new mingw binaries

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I updated my mingw binaries to support c++11 and now I can't compile my code.

I am working with a cygwin and including the binaries in the PATH enviroment variable.

This is my includes and first lines in main:

```
#include "icm/icmCpuManager.hpp"
#include "Instruction.hpp"
#include "MicroblazeInstruction.hpp"
#include "CpuManager.hpp"
#include "File.hpp"
#include "Utils.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
```

Which take me to my first lines in File.hpp

```
#ifndef FILE_HPP
#define FILE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
```

This is my makefile:

```
IMPERAS=$(IMPERAS_HOME)
ifndef IMPERAS
  IMPERAS := $(error "IMPERAS paths not defined")
endif

SUFFIX=.cpp
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -c -I $(IMPERAS_HOME)/ImpPublic/include/host/ -std=c++11
LDFLAGS=-m32 -L$(IMPERAS_HOME)/bin/$(IMPERAS_ARCH) -lRuntimeLoader  

EXECUTABLE=./faith.exe
SRC=./main.cpp ./CpuManager.cpp ./Instruction.cpp ./File.cpp ./Utils.cpp
OBJS=$(SRC:.cpp=.o)
DEPS=

#SHAREDOBJ=$(SRC:.c=.so)

.PHONY: all
#all: $(EXECUTABLE) $(SHAREDOBJ)
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

# platform
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    @    echo "# Linking Platform $@"
    $(V) $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

# platform objects
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    @    echo "# Compiling Platform source: $@"
    $(V) $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# dynamic lib
#$(SHAREDOBJ): $(OBJS)
#   @    echo "# Host Linking Platform object $@"
#   $(V) $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(V) - rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJS)
```

This is my compiling error:

```
$ make
# Compiling Platform source: main.o
g++ -m32 -LC:\Imperas/bin/Windows32 -lRuntimeLoader   -O2 -Wall -c -m32 -I C:\Imperas/ImpPublic/include/host/ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.o
In file included from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:43:0,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/ios:43,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/ostream:40,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/iostream:40,
                 from File.hpp:4,
                 from main.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:45:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'namespace'
In file included from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/cwctype:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/locale_facets.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/basic_ios.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/ios:45,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/ostream:40,
                 from c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/iostream:40,
                 from File.hpp:4,
                 from main.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wctype.h:15:32: error: expected '}' before end of line
c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wctype.h:15:32: error: expected unqualified-id before end of line
c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wctype.h:15:32: error: expected declaration before end of line
makefile:29: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: We can't compile your code either, although a web search of that error seems to imply that a missing semicolon is a frequent cause.

Comment: This is indicating an error inside the iostream...
main.cpp in line 5 is #include <iostream> as is FIle.cpp line 4.

Comment: It was compiling before I updated the binaries.

Comment: Show us *at least* the first 5 lines of main.cpp, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of your file "CpuManager.hpp"

That missing semicolon is triggering an error in the code that immediately follows it, which is identified in your compiler error.

Comment: It was at the end of MicroblazeInstruction.hpp, that was embaracing, thank you so much.